# How to canonicalize xml on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xml-signature, canonicalization

I need to canonicalize an xml file (using c14n standard) in my iOS app for signature validation but I cannot find an API in the iOS SDK which will help me do this. The XML Canonicalization API [canonicalXMLStringPreservingComments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmlnode/1409817-canonicalxmlstringpreservingcomm?language=objc) is available only for the MacOS. Is there any equivalent API or 3rd party library like [XOM](https://xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/canonical/Canonicalizer.html) for this purpose on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a solution for this using [**libxml2**](http://xmlsoft.org/). 
libxml2 contains the required APIs for XML Canonicalization (c14n) and you can find the documentation for it [**here**](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-c14n.html).

**libxml2** is available in the iOS SDK. 
To add the library in your Xcode project:

> - Target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
> - Click on the "+" button and search for "libxml2.tbd"

You will also need to add the following to your project's Build Settings:

> - **Other Linker Flags**: -lxml2
> - **Header Search Paths**: $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

To access libxml2 in your Swift class, simply add:

```
import libxml2
```